# Get error while installing xlrd and while installation get message as requirement satisfied

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook of version 6.5.2. Now when I run my code I get the following error:

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.

So apparently 'xlrd' is not installed. So I went to the Anaconda prompt and tried pip install xlrd, but it replied with

Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\atheena jain\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)

How do I resolve this error?

I tried to import a excel file